Ton nft collection address
What is a NFT Collection formula?
I want to make several NFT collections for a one wallet address. But the collection overwrite each other.
I use default nft-collection.fc file and its ts wrapper.

I can't understand how TON create the address.
What should I modify to create a new nft collection with a new address?

https://github.com/ton-blockchain/token-contract/blob/main/nft/nft-collection.fc

The answer is this address is generated in .ts file
    export declare function contractAddress(workchain: number, stateInit: StateInit): Address;

export interface StateInit {
    splitDepth?: Maybe<number>;
    special?: Maybe<TickTock>;
    code?: Maybe<Cell>;
    data?: Maybe<Cell>;
    libraries?: Maybe<Dictionary<bigint, SimpleLibrary>>;
}

in my case it was a static Cell of data:
beginCell().storeUint(0, 64).endCell();
the doc is here
